# Json -> Android

Tags: android, json

How to convert json in android
There is a message of the form

```
{"type": "message", "data": {"time": 1385077892240, "text": "Hello", "author": false, "color": false}}
```

how to convert to Android

Comment: Not sure what your question is really asking here.

Comment: What have you tried? You can hardly expect us to do your work without showing you've actually put some effect into attempting to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

String strJSON;
JSONObject json;

strJSON = "{\"type\": \"message\", \"data\": {\"time\": 1385077892240, \"text\": \"Hello\", \"author\": false, \"color\": false}}";

try {
json = new JSONObject(strJSON);
Log.d("JSON-Obj", json.getString("type"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your question is how to use json format in java, there will be many third party library u can found by google. I don't use java, but i heard the GSON library which is provided by google.